# Assigning value directly to std::map on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, global-variables, stdstring, stdmap

I have std::map which contains a std::string and structure inside as a elements.

My header file looks like;

```
struct stFBInterfaceSpec {
    char   numOfEventInputs;
    char** EventInputsName;
    char   numOfEventOutputs;`
    char** EventOutputsName;
    char   numOfDataInputs;
    char** DataInputsName;
    char** DataInputTypeName;
    char   numOfDataOutputs;
    char** DataOutputsName;
    char** DataOutputTypeName;
};

template<typename T>
struct stStd_Fbt_Element {
    stFBInterfaceSpec Fbt_Spec;
    T(*funcPtr)(T, T);
};

typedef std::map<std::string, stStd_Fbt_Element<int>> StdFbts_List;

template<typename T> T ADD(const T pa_roIN1, const T pa_roIN2) {
    return pa_roIN1 + pa_roIN2;
}

template<typename T> T MUL(const T pa_roIN1, const T pa_roIN2) {
    return pa_roIN1 * pa_roIN2;
}

template<typename T> T SUB(const T pa_roIN1, const T pa_roIN2) {
    return pa_roIN1 - pa_roIN2;
}

template<typename T> T DIV(const T pa_roIN1, const T pa_roIN2) {
    return (pa_roIN1 / pa_roIN2);
}

extern StdFbts_List Std_Fbts_List; // to use it on other files

class stdFbts
{
public:
    stdFbts();
    ~stdFbts(){};
};
```

inside main.cpp: (above int main())

```
StdFbts_List Std_Fbts_List; // global declaration

char * arithEiNames[] = { (char *)"REQ"};
char * arithEoNames[] = { (char *)"CNF"};
char * arithDiNames[] = { (char *)"IN1", (char *)"IN2" };
char * arithDiDataType[] = { (char *)"ANY_MAGNITUDE", (char *)"ANY_MAGNITUDE" };
char * arithDoNames[] = { (char *)"OUT" };
char * arithDoDataType[] = { (char *)"ANY_MAGNITUDE"};

stFBInterfaceSpec Arithmetic = { 
    1, arithEiNames, 
    1, arithEoNames, 
    2, arithDiNames, arithDiDataType,
    1, arithDoNames, arithDiDataType
};
```

and my class looks like:

```
stdFbts::stdFbts()
{
    Std_Fbts_List["F_ADD"] = { Arithmetic, ADD };
    Std_Fbts_List["F_DIV"] = { Arithmetic, DIV };
    Std_Fbts_List["F_MUL"] = { Arithmetic, MUL };
    Std_Fbts_List["F_SUB"] = { Arithmetic, SUB };
}

int main(void)
{
    new stdFbts();
    while(1);
}
```

The above code compiles and works fine on VS2013, but when I tried the same code on linux, it throws segmentation fault.

Note: To avoid warning, I have typecasted `string to char *` on the above program. Also the function ADD, SUB, DIV, MUL is located on different header file on my actual project.

Is there any solution to assign string values to global variables.
I define CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS as `"-std=c++11 -Wpointer-arith -W -Wall -Wextra -Woverloaded-virtual -Wconversion -Wfloat-conversion -Wpointer-arith -Wno-write-strings -ggdb"`and my gcc version is 4.9.3.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger to see which line causes the segfault?

Comment: Std_Fbts_List["F_ADD"] = { Arithmetic, ADD }; it gives exception here..

Comment: #5  0x00000001004534c2 in std::map<std::string, stStd_Fbt_Element<int>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, stStd_Fbt_Element<int> > > >::operator[](std::string&&) (this=0x1004955a0 <Std_Fbts_List>,
    __k=<unknown type in /cygdrive/c/BitBucket_Repo/fourzerorte_prism_0p1p19/FourZero.RTE/bin/posix/src/fzrte.exe, CU 0x289c2f, DIE 0x2a808b>)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:519
#6  0x000000010043d3b5 in stdFbts::stdFbts (this=0x60003b1f0) at C:/BitBucket_Repo/fourzerorte_prism_0p1p19/FourZero.RTE/src/core/stdFbts.cpp:176

Comment: Add additional information [in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34216947/edit), not in comments.

Comment: From your error, have you looked at stl_map.h, line 519, where the crash is occurring?  It's in map's `operator[]`.

Comment: Yes, 0x0000000100451f46 in std::map<std::string, stFBInterfaceSpec*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, stFBInterfaceSpec*> > >::insert<std::pair<char const*, stFBInterfaceSpec*>, void>(std::pair<char const*, stFBInterfaceSpec*>&&) (this=0x100495680 <ldummy>,
    __x=<unknown type in /cygdrive/c/BitBucket_Repo/fourzerorte_prism_0p1p19/FourZero.RTE/bin/posix/src/fzrte.exe, CU 0x289c2f, DIE 0x2b102b>)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:638

Comment: I really don't have any idea why it is giving unknown type

Comment: Once I figured out what I was tripping over (char   numOfEventOutputs;**`**), this is a good question. All the information needed is here, sadly I can't reproduce.

Comment: The proper way to deal with type conversion warnings is not to cast but to use the correct types.

Comment: "cygdrive" means it is CygWin, not Linux.

Comment: As per @Zeta's request, would you move the items of code in comments above into the question, [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34216947/edit)? They will be more readable there, and then you can de-clutter the conversation by deleting them from the comments.